How do I remotely access my computer from a different location in a safe and reliable way?
I have a question! I have a really nice PC at home that I built a couple of years ago, but in a few months I'm moving temporarily and leaving this PC at home. My question is, how do I set it up such that I can remotely access it from my new location? I want to be able to:

Remotely power it on
Remotely use it and do work like video editing
Do any updates if necessary
Also, how do I make it as safe as possible??


I have enabled "Remote Desktop" and Wake on LAN (It has Windows 10 Pro), but I don't know how to access it from a different network using the Remote Desktop App or make it turn on from a different network.

If you get Public IP (routable IP) from your ISP, you can use DDNS feature in your router (and DDNS provider) to create a DNS entry and use tools like Wake On LAN GUI to remotely turn it on. You can also configure Softether VPN Server and Client to make a VPN connection to your PC and then use RDP.

In addition to Remote Desktop or an alternative, you'll need a virtual private network (VPN) at both ends to access it safely, to prevent others from taking over the PC. Microsoft outlines how that might be done. AnyViewer and ProPrivacy also describe this.

Allow traffic from the outside through the router.
Obtain a permanent public IP address from your internet service provider (ISP). In some cases, there might be additional costs.
Get VPN licenses for both the home PC and that you're taking with you.


Caveats
While traveling, you might find an ISP does not allow use of VPN.
Operating a PC remotely poses additional loads; that fast PC at home might not be quite so fast when operated remotely, particularly on an intensive task such as video editing. Also, at each end, a VPN goes through additional servers, so you'd want a reasonably high-speed service. Test the VPN to see how Remote Desktop functions before leaving on that trip.
Also, consider that Wake on LAN leaves the machine always on, albeit in a low-power state. Unless there is someone at home to help, access may be lost should it actually power down or crash. After performing an update on the remote PC, for example, access may be lost until a helper at it reconnects it to the web.
Because of those complexities and limitations, rather than use remote access, I'd be inclined to take as much information as possible, even to the extent of making a disk image of the home PC on a portable drive. As for storing information while traveling, I'd make backups to that portable drive, as well as to cloud storage services such as Box.com, Dropbox, and others, when available. And for editing videos, you might let the task wait.
